# Looping in R to sum for all times older than t

Tags: r

I have a series of net carbon uptake values (NCU) with time. I want to create a new series of net carbon release values (NCR) with time through a loop based on the following:

1. The NCR at time `t` is the sum of `C` release during that period of all other times older than time `t`.
2. The `C` release during the period at time `t` can be calculated by the difference of potential NCUs at time `t` and time `t−1`.
3. NCU is added at the beginning of each period.

The paper I am using to base the model off of states that this is a mathematical trick for keeping track of decomposition at various time intervals. The equation is `NCRsubt = sum(NCUsub[t] - NCUsub[t-1])` from `t=1` to `t = T`.

This is what I have in R so far:

```
dt = 0.005          # Time step in years 
duration = 15       # Simulation runs for 15, 500 yr intervals 
n = duration/dt + 1 # Number of step including the starting point 
time = (0:(n-1))*dt # The time in unit 500 yr intervals

NCR = numeric(n)

for (i in 1:(n-1)){

 NCR[i] = NCU[i] + (NCU[i] - NCU[i-1]) 

}
```

I can't figure out how to accomplish making `NCR[i]` the sum of the loop above for all times less than a given time.

NCU has two variables, `time(x)`  (in 500 year intervals)  which is `1:15`, and `NCU (y)`.

**Edit**

Here are sample values:

**NCU values**

> NCU = c(52.02080416,55.0440176,77.09245546,80.12810245,71.14214209,60.14417294,36.10094125,66.21153828,64.23081522,61.24448865,54.23812349)

**NCUt - NCUt-1 values**

> NCUt_NCUt_1 = c(-3.023213444,-22.04843786,-3.035646992,8.98596036,10.99796916,24.04323169,-30.11059703,1.980723063,2.986326567,7.006365164)

**NCRt values**

> NCRt = c(10.77406468,13.79727813,35.84571598,38.88136298,29.89540262,18.89743346,-5.145798226,24.9647988,22.98407574,19.99774917)

Excel Screenshot of the calculations:

[image: Excel screenshot of the calculations]

Comment: I don't think you need a loop, but `cumsum` might be helpful.

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible by sharing some starting values? For illustrative purposes doing, say, 5 time steps and showing input and desired output would help make things very clear.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @Gregor. Here are some example data:
**NCU values**
52.02080416
55.0440176
77.09245546
80.12810245
71.14214209
60.14417294
36.10094125
66.21153828
64.23081522
61.24448865
54.23812349

**NCUt - NCUt-1 values**
-3.023213444
-22.04843786
-3.035646992
8.98596036
10.99796916
24.04323169
-30.11059703
1.980723063
2.986326567
7.006365164

**NCRt values**
10.77406468
13.79727813
35.84571598
38.88136298
29.89540262
18.89743346
-5.145798226
24.9647988
22.98407574
19.99774917

Comment: Thank you for the edits, @Coatless

Comment: Please edit into your question (very hard to read in the comments!) and also be explicit about what are inputs and what are outputs. Is the entire `NCU` vector known up front and it is just `NCR` that needs to be calculated?

Comment: Yes, the entire `NCU` vector is known (input) and I am trying to find `NCR` (output).

Comment: @SaraMiller are you sure the difference is correct? I'm getting opposite signs under `diff(NCU)`.

Comment: Can you write out the excel formulas you are using?

Comment: @Coatless it looks like that is taking t-1 - t. I should clarify that the order of time is from newest to oldest, so values should be subtracted in descending order.

Comment: column K is NCU values, ordered by 500 year interval (1 to 15). So 1 is the youngest, 15 is the oldest. NCUt - NCUt-1 = K2 - K3. Then NCRt = SUM(L2:L15), SUM(L3:L15), and so on.

Comment: @SaraMiller awesome. One last thing, could you take a screenshot of the excel doc and upload it?

Comment: [ExcelScreenshot](https://www.amazon.com/clouddrive/share/HLJSiK10gFdfuJk7UjEWOIdqVXWH5sjkCvzn2SwcFC0?v=grid&ref_=cd_ph_share_link_copy).

Comment: @SaraMiller see answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, let's do a quick answer for this.

```
# Load in the data
# This includes the all the data within the screenshot (1:15) vs. (1:11)
NCU = c(52.02080416,55.0440176,77.09245546,80.12810245,71.14214209,60.14417294,36.10094125,66.21153828,64.23081522,61.24448865,54.23812349, 65.31275,58.30238552, 51.28640117, 41.24673948)

# Reverse the difference e.g. -1*([t] - [t-1]) => [t-1]-[t] 
dncu = -1*diff(NCU)

# Here is a function to use within `sapply()`
# The function provides the sum from x up to the length of the differenced
# ncu data.
calc_NCR = function(x, dncu, len_dncu){ 
   sum(dncu[x:len_dncu])
}

# Length of the differenced ncu data
len_dncu = length(dncu)

# A vectorized for loop for speed. 
# range is given from 1 to the length of differenced data. 
sapply(1:len_dncu, FUN = calc_NCR, dncu = ncut_ncut_1, len_dncu = len_dncu)
```

Result (after using `as.matrix()` on the `sapply()` to make it look pretty):

```
           [,1]
 [1,] 10.774065
 [2,] 13.797278
 [3,] 35.845716
 [4,] 38.881363
 [5,] 29.895403
 [6,] 18.897433
 [7,] -5.145798
 [8,] 24.964799
 [9,] 22.984076
[10,] 19.997749
[11,] 12.991384
[12,] 24.066011
[13,] 17.055646
[14,] 10.039662
```

Comment: Thank you, and thanks for the use of `sapply`, that's easier to understand for this than a `for` loop. This works when I used it with my data.

Answer (score 1):

A supplement to Coatless's nice answer with another method:

```
# as in the other answer
dncu = -1*diff(NCU)
```

The `cumsum` function gives the cumulative sum of a vector, e.g.

```
cumsum(1:5)
# [1]  1  3  6 10 15
```

You want a cumulative sum, but backwards. Instead of first, first + second, first + second + third, ... you are looking for last, last + second-to-last, ...

We can get that by simply reversing the input vector with `rev()`. And then we'll also reverse the result so it's in the right order:

```
rev(cumsum(rev(dncu)))
# [1] 10.774065 13.797278 35.845716 38.881363 29.895403 18.897433 -5.145798 24.964799
# [9] 22.984076 19.997749 12.991384 24.066011 17.055646 10.039662
```

Which is what you're looking for!

---

I do think you're making things a little harder on yourself than they need to be by ordering time backwards. If you ordered time oldest to newest then

```
forwardNCU = rev(NCU)
cumsum(diff(forwardNCU))
```

Gives the same result (in forwards-time order).

Comment: Great solution @Gregor